# Linux command Line find and replace

Tags: command, line

i have a file.txt with contents

2021-12-03;12.20.31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK

2021-12-03;12.33.31;15;00199.94;00000.00;Status OK

2021-12-03;12.35.33; 2;01962.33;00015.48;;Status OK

2021-12-03;13.05.31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK

so what command to output like below

2021-12-03;12:20:31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK

2021-12-03;12:33:31;15;00199.94;00000.00;Status OK

2021-12-03;12:35:33; 2;01962.33;00015.48;Status OK

2021-12-03;13:05:31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK

note.
cut -b 12-19 file.txt (is time)

Thanks for your help.
Rido

Comment: Please edit your question as to what you want changing. It seems you want : changed to .?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the lines you want to modify are contained in a file (which I called filea.txt). The script should solve your problem.

Contents of the file 'filea.txt':

```
$> cat filea.txt
2021-12-03;12.20.31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK   
2021-12-03;12.33.31;15;00199.94;00000.00;Status OK 
2021-12-03;12.35.33; 2;01962.33;00015.48;;Status OK
2021-12-03;13.05.31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK
```

Script File:

```
$> cat refrm
#!/usr/bin/bash                                                      
                                                                 
in_file="filea.txt"                                                      
                                                                 
while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ];                                
do                                                                   
    line=$(echo "${line}" | sed -E 's/;{2,}/;/g')                
    IFS=$'\n'                                                    
    line=$(echo ${line} | sed 's/;/\n/g')                        
    arr=($(IFS='\n' ; echo "${line}"))                           
                                                                 
    for ((n=0; n < ${#arr[*]}; n++))                             
    do                                                           
        if [[ ${arr[n]} =~ ^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} ]]; 
        then                                                 
            arr[n]=`echo ${arr[n]} | sed 's/\./:/g'`     
        fi                                                   
    done                                                         
    nline=$(IFS=";" ; echo "${arr[*]}")                          
    echo "${nline}"                                              
done < ${in_file}
```

Output:

```
$> refrm
2021-12-03;12:20:31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK
2021-12-03;12:33:31;15;00199.94;00000.00;Status OK
2021-12-03;12:35:33; 2;01962.33;00015.48;Status OK
2021-12-03;13:05:31;13;00000.00;00000.00;NO LINK
```